# How to put task switcher on only one monitor (xfce)

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, xfce

I would like to put task switcher only on first monitor, not on all. I use configuration where second monitor (VGA) is on the right of first one (LVDS). Task switcher ivoked by <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> is on both screen.

Answer (score -2):

Applications > System Tools > Preferences > Displays and untick Mirror Displays. After that you can drag and drop displays on that window to the left or right.

Comment: no, no, no... i don't use mirroring displays :) they're separate. when i press alt-tab i see small window in the middle of both displays with list of programs. I would like to put it only on first display :)